# Convert Texture2D to OpenCV Mat?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, unity-game-engine

There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482647/convert-opencv-mat-to-texture2d) about converting OpenCV `cv::Mat` to `Texture2D` in Unity and I provided an answer which works well. Now, I am trying to do the opposite but have been stuck on this for few hours now.

I want to convert Unity's `Texture2D` to OpenCV `cv::Mat` so that I can process the Texture on the C++ side.

Here is the original `Texture2D` in my Unity project that I want to convert to `cv:Mat`:

[image]

Here is what it looks like after converting it into `cv:Mat`:

[image]

It looks so washed out. *I am not worried about the rotation of the image*. I can fix that. Just wondering why it looks so washed out. Also used `cv::imwrite` to save the image for testing purposes but the issue in also in the saved image.

**C# code**:

```
[DllImport("TextureConverter")]
private static extern float TextureToCVMat(IntPtr texData, int width, int height);

unsafe void TextureToCVMat(Texture2D texData)
{
    Color32[] texDataColor = texData.GetPixels32();
    //Pin Memory
    fixed (Color32* p = texDataColor)
    {
        TextureToCVMat((IntPtr)p, texData.width, texData.height);
    }
}

public Texture2D tex;

void Start()
{
    TextureToCVMat(tex);
}
```

**C++ code**:

```
DLLExport void TextureToCVMat(unsigned char*  texData, int width, int height)
{
    Mat texture(height, width, CV_8UC4, texData);

    cvNamedWindow("Unity Texture", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    //cvResizeWindow("Unity Texture", 200, 200);
    cv::imshow("Unity Texture", texture);
    cv::imwrite("Inno Image.jpg", texture);
}
```

---

I also tried creating a `struct` on the C++ side to hold the pixel information instead of using `unsigned char*` but the result is still the-same:

```
struct Color32
{
    uchar r;
    uchar g;
    uchar b;
    uchar a;
};


DLLExport void TextureToCVMat(Color32* texData, int width, int height)
{
    Mat texture(height, width, CV_8UC4, texData);

    cvNamedWindow("Unity Texture", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cvResizeWindow("Unity Texture", 200, 200);
    cv::imshow("Unity Texture", texture);
}
```

Why does the image look so so washed out and how do you fix this?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind would be passing a set of params to `imwrite` like `std::vector<int> params;
params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
params.push_back(100);` and then call `imwrite`.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard Note that I don't care about `imwrite`. I am just using it to debug the image and figure out while it is displaying like that. If `cv::imshow` failed too, `cv::imwrite` should also fail. I just tried it and the problem is still there but nice suggestion

Comment: OpenCV creates the image as `BGRA` by default. `Color32` is RGBA. Use `cv::cvtColor` to convert it to `RGBA`.

Comment: @zindarod I printed [`Texture2D.format`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D-format.html) on the Unity side and it says ["RGB24"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.RGB24.html). Also, I have been trying `cv::cvtColor` with different format even before making this post but those didn't work

Comment: @zindarod but he already has `CV_8UC4` which is a 4 channel 8-bit matrix. I think it's RGBA. I don't know if you tried with gamma correction @Programmer

Comment: In your C++ code, do: `cv::cvtColor(texture,texture,cv::COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)`. As you said the `Texture2D.format` gives `RGB24`, so in your case the alpha channel doesn't matter.

Comment: @zindarod Beautiful. Please leave an answer. There are so many formats and I guess I skipped `COLOR_BGRA2RGBA` during the test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html) creates images as `BGR` by default, whereas [`Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html) stores pixels as `RGBA`. However since OP mentioned in the comments that the `Texture2D.format` gives texture format as `RGB24`, we can ignore the alpha channel altogether.

```
DLLExport void TextureToCVMat(unsigned char*  texData, int width, int height)
{
    Mat texture(height, width, CV_8UC4, texData);
    cv::cvtColor(texture,texture,cv::COLOR_BGRA2RGB);

    cv::imshow("Unity Texture", texture);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

}
```