# Emgucv Image to LoadRawTextureData

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, image-processing, emgucv

I need help for converting Emgucv videoCapture image to LoadRawTextureData of unity to display images/videos in Unity3d 2018.1.

I am able to display images but it show strange lines and distorted image effects or some kind of shuttering/scattering.

I read the question in this post and apply the solution but the problem is not solved [Convert Mat to Texture2d(Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482647/convert-opencv-mat-to-texture2d)

I think the Colorspace of Emgucv image did not matched with the texture2d.

**Code:**

```
void Start () {
    vc = new VideoCapture(0);

    vc.FlipVertical = true;    //The image I am getting from webcam is flipped 
    myMaterial = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

    frameHeight = (int)vc.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameHeight);
    frameWidth = (int)vc.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameWidth);

    camera = new Texture2D(frameHeight,frameWidth, TextureFormat.RGB24, false,false);

}
```

I am getting images in this part of code and converting the color space as per texture2d format.

```
void Update () {
    Mat secondimage = new Mat();
    Mat myimage = vc.QueryFrame();

    CvInvoke.CvtColor(myimage, secondimage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorConversion.Bgr2Rgb);
    Image<Rgb, byte> hello = secondimage.ToImage<Rgb, byte>();
    camera.LoadRawTextureData(hello.bytes);
    camera.Apply();
    myMaterial.mainTexture = camera;
}
```

**Results:**

The Result is kind of strange,take a look on following result images.
This is my hand holding in Front of camera.This image is orignal texture2d image.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWnCn.png)

This image is displayed on the 3d plane in unity3d.

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgtzW.png)

As code explain i already Convert image **Bgr2Rgb**.

**update:**

I simply exchange the width and height in **texture2d** and wow it worked.

```
camera = new Texture2D(frameWidth, frameHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24,false,false);
```

Comment: Replace `ColorConversion.Bgr2Rgb` with `ColorConversion.Rgb2Bgra`

Comment: Nope! Did not worked for me.