# How can I convert OpenCV Mat to Texture2D in Unity using C# script?

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I just want to convert Mat type variable to Texture2D type.

I can convert texture2D to mat and this only use EncodeToJPG() function.
like this:

```
Mat mat = Mat.FromImageData(_texture.EncodeToPNG());
```

Texture2D -> Mat is easy...but I cannot convert **"MAT -> Texture2D"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With opencvsharp, use `Mat.GetArray` to get the byte array data of the mat then loop over it based on the the height and width of the mat. Copy the mat data to `Color32` in that loop and finally use `Texture2D.SetPixels32()` and `Texture2D.Apply()` to set and apply the pixel.

```
void MatToTexture(Mat sourceMat) 
{
    //Get the height and width of the Mat 
    int imgHeight = sourceMat.Height;
    int imgWidth = sourceMat.Width;

    byte[] matData = new byte[imgHeight * imgWidth];

    //Get the byte array and store in matData
    sourceMat.GetArray(0, 0, matData);
    //Create the Color array that will hold the pixels 
    Color32[] c = new Color32[imgHeight * imgWidth];

    //Get the pixel data from parallel loop
    Parallel.For(0, imgHeight, i => {
        for (var j = 0; j < imgWidth; j++) {
            byte vec = matData[j + i * imgWidth];
            var color32 = new Color32 {
                r = vec,
                g = vec,
                b = vec,
                a = 0
            };
            c[j + i * imgWidth] = color32;
        }
    });

    //Create Texture from the result
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(imgWidth, imgHeight, TextureFormat.RGBA32, true, true);
    tex.SetPixels32(c);
    tex.Apply();
}
```

---

If you're not using opencvsharp but making the plugin yourself with C++ and C# then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482647/convert-opencv-mat-to-texture2d/49486419#49486419) post.